# Solving a polynomial with three variables and two opposite zeros.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

$f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c ,a,b,c \in \mathbb R $

Two zeros of the polynomial are additive inverses.

a. Show that $ab = c$.

b. Find the third zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that the zeros of the given equation are $p,-p, q$

Now, $\frac{-a}{1} = p +(-p)+q \Rightarrow a=-q$

Also, $ (-p)(p)+(p)(q)+(-p)(q) = \frac{b}{1} \Rightarrow b= -p^2$

And $ (p)(-p)(q) = \frac{-c}{1} \Rightarrow c=p^2q$

Multiplying the first 2 equations, you get $ab=p^2q$ or $ab=c$

Hence, the desired result is achieved, Note that this involves basic knowledge of the properties of a cubic equation.

Answer (score 0):

If two of the roots are opposite and the polynomial is monic, then the polynomial can be written as $$(x-r)(x+r)(x-s)=(x^2-r^2)(x-s)=x^3-sx^2-r^2x+r^2s$$

Since $a=-s,b=-r^2$ and $c=+r^2s$, then $ab=(-s)(-r^2)=r^2s=c$.